# Rewarded Video Ads for Facebook Instant Game not working for me, but working for client

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

I am developing a Facebook Instant Game for a client and my task is to integrate some Rewarded Video Ads.

I've already put the basic code which loads the video ads and my client says they are able to watch the videos successfully on their side.

However, I am unable to see it on my account / device. I always get the ADS_NO_FILL error.

As a test, I tried to play Video Ads from other Instant Games, but I also couldn't view them. My client however says that they're able to view ads on other Instant Games as well.

Would be nice if someone had an idea what could be going on. Is this expected? Is it normal to get ADS_NO_FILL all the time?

Here's the code I'm using just in case:

```
FBInstant.getRewardedVideoAsync(AD_PLACEMENT_ID).then((rewarded) => {

    // Load the Ad asynchronously
    DebugScreen.log('Load the Ad asynchronously'); 
    preloadedRewardedVideo = rewarded;
    return preloadedRewardedVideo.loadAsync();

}).then(() => {
    DebugScreen.log('Rewarded video preloaded..');

    preloadedRewardedVideo.showAsync().then(() => {
        // Perform post-ad success operation
        DebugScreen.log('Video watched successfully');       
    }).catch((e) => {
        DebugScreen.log(e.message);
    });

}).catch((err) => {
    DebugScreen.log('Video failed to preload.. msg: ' + err.message + ', code: ' + err.code);
});
```

Comment: If you are not a developer on the app and the placement has not gone through review, then you will not be able to view ads. That seems most likely for what is going on here. It could also be that you're in a geography that does not have much  ad inventory but that is less likely.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply @ChrisHawkins, I tried to play the game using a VPN set to a different country and the ads now seem to successfully preload (as I'm able to get the "Rewarded Video preloaded" debug message). However, when its time to play the video, I get an ADS_NOT_LOADED / "Failed to show ad" error message. Any ideas?